# Parsing Mongooses Date type in Kotlin, Android? (2020-12-07T12:24:00.624+00:00 type of format)

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, kotlin, mongoose

I have a custom Nodejs backend with Mongoose and Mongodb, I save my model inside mongo and I use the Date type to indicate when it was saved. I'd like to parse this date inside my android application and add a when it was posted (5 days ago, a day ago, minute ago, etc etc).

In the server

```
 date: {
    type: Date, default: Date.now
  },
```

Comes out as `2020-12-07T12:24:00.624+00:00`

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat.parse` then `RelativeDateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @Nicolas I am not quite sure what you mean about RelativeDateTimeFormatter, it doesnt seem to be what I need. I ended up using ZonedDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME). I get a date of this format 2020-12-09T15:02:43.017Z. It's better than what I've had atleast

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat.parse` parses a date string to a time in milliseconds since epoch (a long), given a pattern which can include a time zone. I don't know about ZonedDateTime, it might do the same. And yes I was mistaken, it's not the right class. I meant [`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long)) which takes a long date argument

Comment: I would use an `OffsetDateTime` instead of a `ZonedDateTime`, but in general, using `java.time` should be preferred nowadays.

Comment: Can I ask for an answer with the implementation of your comment? I've tried looking into all of the classes you mentioned but cannot seem to find the same methods you are talking about, no method returns Long or accepts a format. Thank you!